# Jasmine 1.3 - is it possible to unspy?

Tags: jasmine

We can define the following test:

`spyOn(x, 'funk').andReturn(true);`

If we then wanted to define:

`spyOn(x, 'funk').andReturn(false);`

We would get an error saying that `funk` had already been spied on.

How could we effectively `unspy` so that could respy with the new return value?

Answer (score 5):

You can re-train spies:

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
x = {
    funk: function() {
        return 1;
    }
}

// --- SPECS -------------------------

describe('test x', function () {

    it("trains spies", function () {
        spyOn(x, 'funk');
        x.funk.andReturn('a');
        expect(x.funk()).toBe('a');
        x.funk.andCallThrough();
        expect(x.funk()).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/88kvnzx3/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to unspy.

As the spy is just a function that replaces whatever function you want to spy on, you can replace it again with another function.

Two sensible ways of doing this are as follows - first, just add an empty function, Jasmine will have all it needs for a new spy:

`x.funk = function() {}`

Or, if the functionality of original function is important, just store it in a value like so:

```
var tempFunk = x.funk
/* do stuff */
x.funk = tempFunk
```